# Column name is specified more than once EF Code First Migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two columns in a table which I created them using code first approach then I changed their data types in the C# model not the actual database and last I tried the later migration in order to change their data type in the database

```
public partial class PriceAndMargin : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Items", "Price", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.Items", "ShortageMargin", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.Items", "ShortageMargin");
        DropColumn("dbo.Items", "Price");
    }
}
```

If I got it write this code should drop the Price column and the ShortageMargin column and recreates them
but instead it displays this message in the console for me

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Price' in table 'dbo.Items' is specified more than once

thanks in advance

Comment: Describe your entire workflow. Did you add the Price column to the table yourself, or in an earlier migration?

Comment: no I used the above migration @CodeCaster

Comment: The steps you took are unclear, and the code does not correspond to your description. The migration you show adds two columns. One of the columns already exists.

Comment: I wrote above that those two columns already existed but with different data types I created them using code first approach then I changed their data types in the C# model not the actual database and last I tried to migration above in order to change their data type in the database @CodeCaster

Comment: shouldn't the DropColumn solve this problem @marc_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I got it write this code should drop the Price column and the ShortageMargin column and recreates them

Not really, your "up" adds the columns. The "down" section is only if you want to "downgrade" your database (ou revert the migration).
I don't know how you changed the type of your object, and from which version you ran the 'add-migration' command but you should have a script with "***AlterColumn*** instead of ***AddColumn***